# Api controller declaring more than one Get statement

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-routing

Using the new Api Controller in MVC4, and I've found a problem.  If I have the following methods:

`public IEnumberable<string> GetAll()`

`public IEnumberable<string> GetSpecific(int i)`

This will work.  However, if I want to retrieve some different data of a different type, it defaults to the `GetAll` method, even though the `$.getJSON` is set to the `GetAllIntegers` method:

`public IEnumberable<int> GetAllIntergers()`

*(bad naming conventions)*

Is it possible for me to be able to do this?

Can I only have a single `GetAll` method in the Web API controller?

I think it's easier to visualise what I'm trying to achieve.  Here is a snippet of code to show what I'd like to be able to do, in a single `ApiController`:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetClients()
{ // Get data
}

public IEnumerable<string> GetClient(int id)
{ // Get data
}

public IEnumerable<string> GetStaffMember(int id)
{ // Get data
}

public IEnumerable<string> GetStaffMembers()
{ // Get data
}
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

This is all in the routing. The default Web API route looks like this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( 
    name: "API Default", 
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}", 
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional } 
);
```

With the default routing template, Web API uses the HTTP method to select the action. In result it will map a GET request with no parameters to first `GetAll` it can find. To work around this you need to define a route where the action name is included:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( 
   name: "ActionApi", 
   routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
   defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional } 
);
```

After that you can star making requests with following URL's:

- api/yourapicontroller/GetClients
- api/yourapicontroller/GetStaffMembers

This way you can have multiple `GetAll` in Controller.

One more important thing here is that with this style of routing, you must use attributes to specify the allowed HTTP methods (like [HttpGet]).

There is also an option of mixing the default Web API verb based routing with traditional approach, it is very well described here:

- [Web API: Mixing Traditional & Verb-Based Routing](http://blog.appliedis.com/2013/03/25/web-api-mixing-traditional-verb-based-routing/)

Comment: Quick question, can I route like this and still call my methods only "Post" and have them automatically only accept HttpPost if I include an ActionNameAttribute?

Comment: @Alxandr You will still have to use AcceptVerbsAttribute (or HttpPostAttribute, HttpGetAttribute etc.)

Comment: I'm having some problems with the routing - I can define multiple "GET" methods, but if I hit /api/{controller} the server gives an HTTP 500 "multiple actions found" rather than a 404. Any idea how to block this? What I'd like is to have /api/{controller}/{id} route to "Get, Post, Put, Delete,etc ", then have /api/{controller}/{id}/{action} route to a specific action, such as /api/Customers/5/Products. Doesn't work - everything gives a "multiple actions found" error.

Comment: @tpeczek I am having the same problem. Should the routing with the extra {action} replace the default routing or should it be added after it?

Comment: @uriDium It looks like you are looking for mixing traditional & verb based routing, you can read more about it here: http://blog.appliedis.com/2013/03/25/web-api-mixing-traditional-verb-based-routing/

Comment: Mine isn't working. I have two separate functions, however it only returns one of them.

Comment: @Si8 Please provider more details or reach me via email - I'll try to help.

Comment: @tpeczek Thank you. I had to add [HttpGet] for each function and it worked fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

In case someone else faces this problem. Here's how I solved this. Use the [Route] attribute on your controller to route to a specific url.

```C#
[Route("api/getClient")]
public ClientViewModel GetClient(int id)

[Route("api/getAllClients")]
public IEnumerable<ClientViewModel> GetClients()
```

Comment: route attribute link for those even more curious as to what this format is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: if your method does not start with "Get", be sure to decorate it with [HttpGet]