# Why are an MVC4 ApiControllers' methods called only based on the type and number of parameters?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm new to MVC, and I guess my confusion goes a bit beyond the title of this question, but for starters:

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public bool ReceiveHunk(Alterity.Models.Async.HunkDTO hunk)
    {
        return true;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public bool A(int x) { return false; }
    [HttpPost]
    public bool B(int x) { return true; }
}
```

I can't call my choice of A or B because it seems that the URL only routes to (is that the right term?) the controller, and the method is chosen based on the parameters. Since I have an (int x) on two methods, it doesn't know which to call. My confusion is exacerbated by the fact that when I do:

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    url: ApiLocation + 'Test',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(5),
    success: function (response) { }
});
```

It still goes to the ReceiveHunk method, with the hunk being null. If I comment out B, ReceiveHunk is still called. Is this related to the fact that I'm using JSON instead of form url encoding? Do I have to have a separate ApiController for every method that has the same signature? Is there some way to configure the routing (or whatsit) to have the URL include the method name? A regular Controller includes the method name in the URL, why doesn't an ApiController? Furthermore, if I change either A or B take zero parameters, I simply get an internal server error (500) without any method being called and no exception.  Any info that helps clear this up would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just the default routing convention for ASP.NET Web API, please read following question/answer for more details on how you can configure ASP.NET Web API routing (and have action names in routes):

- [Api controller declaring more than one Get statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121152/api-controller-declaring-more-than-one-get-statement/10122413#10122413)