# Routing in Asp.net Mvc 4 and Web Api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api

Can I use the following two route rule together ?

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ActionApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional } );

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Say by controller is = `FruitApiController:ApiController` and I wish to have the following

1. `List<Fruit> Get()` = `api/FruitApi/`
2. `List<Fruit> GetSeasonalFruits()` = `api/FruitApi/GetSeasonalFruit`
3. `Fruit GetFruits(string id)` = `api/FruitApi/15`
4. `Fruit GetFruitsByName(string name)` = `api/FruitApi/GetFruitsByName/apple`

Please help me on this. Thanks

Comment: interesting. my guess would be that controller/id would use the default index() action.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Web Api Routing for multiple Get methods in ASP.NET MVC 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775590/web-api-routing-for-multiple-get-methods-in-asp-net-mvc-4)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You could have a couple of routes:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ApiById",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { id = @"^[0-9]+$" }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ApiByName",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{name}",
            defaults: null,
            constraints: new { name = @"^[a-z]+$" }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ApiByAction",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { action = "Get" }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ApiByName",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{name}",
            defaults: null,
            constraints: new { name = @"^[a-z]+$" }
        );
```