# Web api with two get actions

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a Test controller with the following -

```
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "hi from test " + id;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public string Search(string text)
        {
            return "you searched for  " + text;
        }
```

I can call

```
 - http://localhost:58635/api/Test/2
 - http://localhost:58635/api/Test?id=2
 - http://localhost:58635/api/Test/Search?text=textToSearcFor
```

but NOT `http://localhost:58635/api/Test/Search/textToSearcFor`

My routes are like those in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775887/routing-in-asp-net-mvc-4-and-web-api)

```
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                  name: "ApiById",
                  routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                  defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
                  constraints: new { id = @"^[0-9]+$" }
              );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ApiByName",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{name}",
            defaults: null
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ApiByAction",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { action = "Get" }
        );
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your "ApiByName" route, Try changing

```
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{name}"
```

to

```
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{text}",
```

**Or**

Change the parameter name "text" of your Search action to "name"

Comment: doh, slap head repeatedly! Thank you