# Asp.Net Mvc Web Api Routing issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I use Web Api for list of tales and I want to do this:

1. List GetAllTales() = api/tales/
2. Tale GetTale(int id) = api/tales/1
3. List GetAllTalesByCategory(string categoryName) = api/tales/kids
4. Tale GetTalesByCategoryAndId(string categoryName, int id) = api/tales/kids/1

I dont know what can ı do this or what can I change in route config?

My TalesController:ApiController

```
public IEnumerable<Tale> GetAllTales()
    {
        return TaleService.FindAllTale();
    }
public IEnumerable<Tale> GetAllTalesByCategory(string categoryName){}

    public Tale GetTale(int id)
    {
        Tale item = TaleService.FindByTaleId(id);
        if (item == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
        }

        return item;
    }
```

Its my WebApiConfig

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { id = @"^[0-9]+$" }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ApiByName",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{name}",
            defaults: null,
            constraints: new { name = @"^[a-z]+$" }
        );
```

Some example for my aim : http://www.bbc.com/news/ - http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology/

Answer (score 0):

use the `[HttpPost]` and `[HttpGet]` attributes and specify the action name with `[ActionName("Your Action Name")]`

```
// api/tales/getall
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("getall")]
public IEnumerable<Tale> GetAllTales()
{
    return TaleService.FindAllTale();
}
```

like this you can decorate all the action with proper attributes to get it working as expected.

**Edit**

You can refer this answer for creating multiple routes [Routing in Asp.net Mvc 4 and Web Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775887/routing-in-asp-net-mvc-4-and-web-api)

Comment: Thanks for answer. I got it and I change my code but if ı write "/api/tales/kids" this request use GetTale(int id). And I didnt use [ActionName] with GetAllTalesByCategory function. Because this function have a lot of thing(entertainment...). I think I have to write diffirent MapRoute.

Comment: see my edit it has an SO question which help you to create multiple routes.

Comment: I see and try something like that but again I didnt do it. So I change a little my question. Now it's more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApiAction", 
        routeTemplate: "api/{action}/{name}/{controller}/{resourceId}",
        defaults: new { resourceId= RouteParameter.Optional }
        constraints: new { name = @"^[a-z]+$" }
    );
```

maybe you can try define this route ,and add ActionName like Anto's answer .