# Asp.Net Mvc Web Api Routing 404

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I try to something on Web Api. First I will share my WebApiConfig

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { id = @"^[0-9]+$" }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ApiCategory",
            routeTemplate: "api/tales/{category}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Tales", id = RouteParameter.Optional},
            constraints: new { category = @"^[a-z]+$" }
        );
```

I read this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775887/routing-in-asp-net-mvc-4-and-web-api) and I fix my apiconfig file. My purpose like this:

1. List GetAllTales() = api/tales/ -> 404 Not Found
2. Tale GetTale(int id) = api/tales/1 -> Ok!
3. List GetAllTalesByCategory(string categoryName) = api/tales/kids -> Ok!
4. Tale GetTalesByCategoryAndId(string categoryName, int id) = api/tales/kids/1 -> Ok!

İf u wonder my ApiController

```
[HttpGet]
    public Tale GetAllTalesByCategoryAndId(string category, int id){}

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Tale> GetAllTalesByCategory(string category){}

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Tale> GetAllTales(){}

    [HttpGet]
    public Tale GetTale(int id){}
```

Thanks for all replies.

Comment: Put your custom route before the default one or the default one will pick up your requests.

Comment: Actually I dont get it. İf I put costum route /api/tales/kids gives an error. Because this send a request GetTale(int id).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to switch the route order. Default route will handle the request when you don't specify an id (api/tales) so you need to place your custom route before that.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "ApiCategory",
        routeTemplate: "api/tales/{category}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Tales", 
                        id = RouteParameter.Optional, 
                        category = RouteParameter.Optional});

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
        constraints: new { id = @"^[0-9]+$" }
    );
```

Comment: I got it. How can I switch the routes? As u said I didn't use constraint for default route. But if I can do it(delete constraint) /api/tales/kids send a request GetTale(int id). I dont know how can I fix it.

Comment: Actually I dont have custom route. I have two route and it's here :/

Comment: @BerdaN ApiCategory is the custom route.

Comment: Hocam kusura bakma 2 saattir uğraşıyorum kafam döndü. Senin dediğin gibi yaptım ApiCategory üstte onun altında DefaultApi var ama yine /api/tales/ 404 dönüyor.

Comment: @BerdaN İlginç. Bende aynı route'larla /api/tales cevap veriyor. Sadece api/tales/kids hata veriyor, o da id nullable olmadığı için.

Comment: Cidden ilginç. .Net frameworkünden kaynaklanıyor olabilir mi? .Net Framework 4.5 i kullanıyorum.

Comment: @BerdaN Cevabı güncelledim. Tekrar dener misin? category de optional olmak zorunda. Regex'i kaldırmak zorunda kaldım, ona bakman lazım. id için integer constraint'i koyabilirsin belki.

Comment: Sağol hocam denedim ama bu seferde api/tales/2 isteği GetAllTalesByCategory(string category) ye giriyor diğerlerinde sorun yok.

Comment: Sırarsını değiştirdim route ların yani DefaultApi üstte olunca api/tales/2 isteği direk ona geldi ve bu sorunum çözüldü. Tekrar teşekkür ederim.