# How to map WebAPI routes correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm building an API for a Twitter like site using Web API and have trouble with mapping the routes

I have the following actions for the User controller:

```
public User Get(string firstname, string lastname)
public User Get(Guid id)
public User Friends(Guid id)
public User Followers(Guid id)
public User Favorites(Guid id)
```

The desired routes and the generated documentation should be:

```
api/users?firstname={firstname}&lastname={lastname}
api/users/{id}
api/users/{id}/friends
api/users/{id}/followers
api/users/{id}/favorites
```

In WebApiConfig.cs I have:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "2",
    "api/{controller}/{id}",
    new { action = "get", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);


config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
     "1",
     "api/{controller}/{id}/{action}"
);
```

How can I map WebAPI routes correctly?

Answer (score 42):

Given the flexibility you want you should take a look at

[Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

In WebApiConfig.cs enable attribute routing like

```
// Web API routes
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

In UserController

**Note** given the names of actions `Friends, Followers and Favorites` they imply returning collections rather than single user

```
[RoutePrefix("api/users")]
public class UserController: ApiController {

    //eg: GET api/users?firstname={firstname}&lastname={lastname}
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public User Get([FromUri]string firstname,[FromUri] string lastname) {...}

    //eg: GET api/users/{id}
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id:guid}")]
    public User Get(Guid id){...}

    //eg: GET api/users/{id}/friends
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id:guid}/friends")]
    public IEnumerable<User> Friends(Guid id){...}

    //eg: GET api/users/{id}/followers
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id:guid}/followers")]
    public IEnumerable<User> Followers(Guid id){...}

    //eg: GET api/users/{id}/favorites
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id:guid}/favorites")]
    public IEnumerable<User> Favorites(Guid id){...}
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Routing is order sensitive. The *first* match always wins. So it is important that you order your routes from most-specific to least-specific.

```
// All parameters are required, or it won't match.
// So it will only match URLs 4 segments in length
// starting with /api.
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
     "1",
     "api/{controller}/{id}/{action}"
);

// Controller is required, id is optional.
// So it will match any URL starting with
// /api that is 2 or 3 segments in length.
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "2",
    "api/{controller}/{id}",
    new { action = "get", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

When your routes are ordered this way, you will get the behavior you expect.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of useful reference materials on this subject, such as:

- [Routing Basics with Web-API](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/624180/Routing-Basics-in-ASP-NET-Web-API)
- [Web-API Routing for multiple methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775590/web-api-routing-for-multiple-get-methods-in-asp-net-mvc-4)
- [Routing in Asp.net Mvc 4 and Web Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775887/routing-in-asp-net-mvc-4-and-web-api)

Have you had a look at these?

**Update..**

Its better practise to explicitly state which parameter is which, ie:

```
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "2",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { action = "Get", id = RouteParameter.Optional },
    );

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "1",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: null
    );
```

Main thing I could see wrong was you had action / id in the wrong order in route "1".

Comment: looked at all of these