# Web API routing custom methods

Tags: c#, routes, asp.net-web-api

I have the following controller:

```
public class CustomerController : ApiController
{
    private ICustomerService customerService;

    public CustomerController(ICustomerService customerService)
    {
        this.customerService= customerService;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Customer> GetAll()
    {
        return customerService.GetAll();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public Customer GetCustomer(int id)
    {
        //Get customer code...
        return customer;
    }

    [ActionName("Save")]
    [AcceptVerbs("PUT")]
    [HttpPost]
    public int SaveCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        //Save customer code...
        return customer.id;
    }

    [ActionName("Test")]
    [HttpGet]
    public string TestCustomer()
    {
        return "test";
    }

    [HttpDelete]
    public bool DeleteCustomer(int id)
    {
        //Delete customer code...
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have the following default RouteConfig:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

And the following default WebApiConfig:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
    }
}
```

When I try ~api/Customer I get the following error: 
Multiple actions were found that match the request: 
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Customer] GetAll() on type MyApp.API.Controllers.PriceLevelController
System.String TestCustomer() on type MyApp.API.Controllers.CustomerController

What changes to my route config do I need to do so that my default methods as well as my custom methods work when called from the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this error comes when you have multiple get method with same param in your controller.
you have to write another Routes in your config file.

You can refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775590/web-api-routing-for-multiple-get-methods-in-asp-net-mvc-4)