# MVC Web Api calling method not working properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to implement three methods controller

```
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        public IEnumerable<string> Get(int id)
        {
            return new string[] { "sa1", "sa2" };
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<string> password()
        {
            return new string[] { "password", "password" };
        }
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

But When i try to call `http://localhost:49365/api/mycontrollername/password`

it's always showing The request is invalid.

Comment: Can you show us your routing config. Also what is the exact error you are getting? (i.e. 404 not found).

Comment: No it worked i have replace default path withconfig.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to call an api function like    `"http://localhost:49365/api/mycontrollername/password"`

you have to add ActionName attribute on the controller and add route on the Routeconfig.cs;

here is the example

```
    [ActionName("GetEmployees")]
    public IEnumerable<Employee> GETEmployees()
    {
        return _db.Employees.AsNoTracking();
    }

   routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Employees", action = "GetEmployees", id =     UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: I have already done it Sir but thank you very much for giving your valuable time to answer

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is attempting to call `Get(int id)` and then trying to pass the word "password" as the integer parameter. From what I can recall it's down to convention-over-configuration in that when you make a GET request it looks for a method named `Get`. In this case it finds one. Then based on the routing, i.e. after the controller name comes an ID, it looks at the next part of the URL, in this case "password", and then uses that as a value for the `id` argument.

If you were to remove the two `Get` methods you probably find that your URL works, but if you add other `HttpGet` methods you will run into other issues related to "multiple actions found". The following discussion may help if you decide you need to have multiple `HttpGet` methods:

[Web Api Routing for multiple Get methods in ASP.NET MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775590/web-api-routing-for-multiple-get-methods-in-asp-net-mvc-4)