# Calling Web API Methods

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am trying to call the DataByLocation with parameter but its calling DataByLocation function with no parameter. Am I missing something? Below is the code.
Thanks in advance.

**Js Code**

```
 getData:function(){
        var _data = {_location:'ABC'};
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            url: 'ABService/api/ABService/DataByLocation',
            data: JSON.stringify(_data),
            success: this.receivedData                
        });
    }
```

**Controller Code**

```
[HttpPost]
public string DataByLocation(string _location)
{
    return _location;
}
[HttpPost]
public string DataByLocation()
{

    return "no parameter";
}
```

**Config Code**

```
    RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: Do you mean to be setting `contentType`?  Or should you be setting `dataType`?

Comment: @jfriend00 , i think `contentType` is fine. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226169/how-to-pass-json-post-data-to-web-api-method-as-object

Comment: ya as its working for parameter less function.

Comment: If you set `dataType` to JSON, then you wouldn't have to stringify the data yourself (jQuery would do it for you), but it probably can work either way since you've already manually turned it into JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route `api/{controller}/{id}` specifies the parameter name to be "id".

So say you have a Web Api Controller like one below

```
public class AbcApiController : ApiController
{
    public Something Get(string searchTerm)
    {
        return ...;
    }
}
```

and if you try to access `/api/AbcApi/get/hello` where hello is the search term you pass. It wont work because this route will search of `Get` action with a parameter id.

Instead what will work for you, if you do not want to change your route is this

`/api/AbcApi/get?searchTerm=hello`

Plus if you are interested in learning more about web api routing, I would recommend you to read this post - [Web Api Routing for multiple Get methods in ASP.NET MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775590/web-api-routing-for-multiple-get-methods-in-asp-net-mvc-4)

Comment: I am getting " Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) " first need to get rid of this.

Comment: Are you getting this now with this solution or from the start ?

Comment: its resolved by [HttpGet] and assembly issue resolve by installing latest webapi through nuget.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not posted actual class name, i am assuming this to be `TestController`. Keeping that in mind, you can use following URLs for webapi. Assume , this is hosted in http://www.example.com`

If you need execute without `id` , then url will be.

`http://www.example.com/api/Test/DataByLocation`

If with `id` then url will remain same, but you need to pass post object as JSON.

**EDIT**

Since controller name is `ABService` , and virtual directory is `ABService`

URL will be `http://www.example.com/ABService/api/ABService/DataByLocation`

[SOURCE](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api)

Comment: thanks of the reply, but the controller name in this case is ABServiceController.

Comment: actually the name of virtual diectory is ABService thats the url is like 'ABService/api/ABService/DataByLocation', but now ended up with error 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.0.0,.. '