# Unable to run multiple GET methods in single controller

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, rest, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-web-api2

I have created a `WEB API` in `visual studio 2015` using `MySQL` DB. I have three `GET` methods. One is which gives all the data, second one is which gives the result based on `ID` and 3rd one is which should gives result on basis of a serial number. First two methods are working perfect but the last one is not. I have also added multiple Routes in the solution. Below is my code

**WebApiConfig**

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "DefaultApi",
           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
           defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
       );



        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "GetByMsn",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{msn}",
        defaults: null,
        constraints: new { msn = @"^[a-z]+$" }
```

**Controller**

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        try
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Found, mEntities.meters_info_dev.ToList());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
        }
    }


    // GET by ID
    public HttpResponseMessage GetByID(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Found, mEntities.meters_info_dev.SingleOrDefault(m => m.id == id));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
        }
    }


    // GET by serial number
    public HttpResponseMessage GetByMsn(string msn)
    {
        try
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Found, mEntities.meters_info_dev.SingleOrDefault(m=> m.meter_msn == msn));
        }
        catch
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "No Data found");
        }
    }
```

`GetByMsn` is the one which is not working. I have tried to change the routes but still the result is same. The [solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12185249/6854117) and [solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12778214/6854117) given are not working for me.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "GetByMsn",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{msn}",
    defaults: null,
    constraints: new { msn = @"^[a-z]+$" }
```

In above the constraints were alphabetic, I just change it to `@"^[0-9]+$"` and it starts working for me.