# Why I get Get all instead of single when I make a request to a web API with a parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, automapper

Why do I get `All` instead of the `Single` result when I do an HTTP request for a web API like this:

> http://localhost/HR/api/camps/2

I think the second method should be executed but the first one is executed instead:

```
  public IHttpActionResult GetCamps()
    {
        var  camps = _context.CAMPs.ToList()
                    .Select(Mapper.Map<CAMP, CampDTO>);
        return Ok(camps);

    }

    public IHttpActionResult GetCamp(int campCode)
    {
        var camp = _context.CAMPs
            .SingleOrDefault(c => c.CAMP_CODE == campCode);

        if (camp == null)
            return NotFound();

        return Ok(Mapper.Map<CAMP, CampDTO>(camp));

    }
```

Comment: Depends entirely on how your routes are set up, which we don't know.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I didn't make any custom routing here

Comment: you can specify route on action [Route("api/camps/{campCode}")] like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775590/routing-with-multiple-get-methods-in-asp-net-web-api/40397258#40397258

Comment: or if you don't want to specify route u can try this .. http://localhost/HR/api/camps?campCode=2

Comment: Routes are matched in the order as they are declared and when there is a match it won't check further routes, so even if you don't explicitly declare, i guess since the first method can also match with the request it just executes that (to prove that may be you can change the ordering of the methods). But it is always good to explicitly specify the routes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've created a brand new ASP.Net (not core) Web API project in Visual Studio 2017 (I'm on 15.8.0), this is the default contents of `WebApiConfig.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                    name: "DefaultApi",
                    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

You'll notice that it has a mapping for an `id` parameter, but no such mapping for `campCode` (hopefully, that isn't unexpected).

You can either add a separate route or change your parameter name. Or supply `campCode` as a query string parameter instead.

---

For any "why doesn't it call method X instead of Y", you should realise it's always a question of routes. There's a handy [Route Debugger](https://www.nuget.org/packages/routedebugger/) by Phil Haack which you can always add in and help with experimenting/answering this sort of question.

Comment: Yeah here the parameter name is effective !! Thanks a lot

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare-  I just added a bit at the bottom, including a link to Phil Haack's route debugger, which may help you if you're trying to get to grips with routing.